# How can i update a Angular Form Array

Tags: angular

I currently use some Form Arrays in my Angular Reactive form which i initialize with data when i load the form. What i would like to do is reload/ refresh an Form Array like my emails one with updated data.

This is how i currently set the initila values

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    first_name: [this.formData && this.formData.first_name],
    middle_name: [this.formData && this.formData.middle_name],
    last_name: [this.formData && this.formData.last_name],
 
    phones: this.fb.array([...phones]),
    emails: this.fb.array([...this.labeledEmailInputsOrNew(this.formData && this.formData.emails)]),
    recurring_events: this.fb.array([...recurring_events]),
    addresses: this.fb.array([...addresses]),
    
});
this.setInitials();
}
```

and this is the code how i create the form Array for email

```
createLabeledEmailInputs(inputs: IEmail[]): FormGroup[] {
        return inputs.map(input => this.createLabeledEmailInput(input));
    }

labeledEmailInputsOrNew(inputs: IEmail[] = []): FormGroup[] {
        return inputs && inputs.length
            ? this.createLabeledEmailInputs(inputs)
            : [this.createLabeledEmailInput()];
    }



createLabeledEmailInput(data?: IEmail) {
        return this.fb.group({
            id: [data && data.id],
            type: [data && data.type],
            address: [data && data.address],
            name: [data && data.name],
            source: [data && data.source],
            dflt: [data && data.dflt],
            dnmm: [data && data.dnmm],
            bounce: [data && data.bounce],
            otherLabel: [data && data.otherLabel],
        });
    }
```

So my question how can i replace all data in that array with newly reloaded data ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research i found the answer which applies to my case as i have an Array of Form Elements. Since I know the index of my Array i can use the .at(index) to either patch or set values

```
                 this.emails.at(index).patchValue( {
                    id: ta.data.id,
                    type: ta.data.type,
                    address:  ta.data.address,
                    name: ta.data.name,
                    source: ta.data.source,
                    dflt: ta.data.dflt,
                    dnmm: ta.data.dnmm,
                    bounce: ta.data.bounce,
                    otherLabel: ta.data.otherLabel
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use FormGroup.setValue method

```
    const form = new FormGroup({
        first: new FormControl(),
        last: new FormControl()
      });
      
      console.log(form.value);   // {first: null, last: null}
      
      form.setValue({first: 'Nancy', last: 'Drew'});
      console.log(form.value);   // {first: 'Nancy', last: 'Drew'}
```

or FormGroup.patchValue

```
 formgroup.patchValue({name:’Mocrosoft’});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can update the FormArray by calling `setValue` or `patchValue`:

```
updteLabeledEmailInput(data?: IEmail) {
    return this.myForm.setValue([data && data.id,
        data && data.type,
        data && data.address,
        data && data.name,
        data && data.source,
        data && data.dflt,
        data && data.dnmm,
        data && data.bounce,
        data && data.otherLabel,
    ]);
}
```

setValue requires an array that matches the entire structure or the FormArray, while patchValue can take a super-set or sub-set of the array.

Comment: i get that part somewhat but how would i patch a particular email. In my case i have the Form Group which  holds in my case for example the Array of Emails. So there is multiple Arrays in the emails Array . so lets say for example there is 3 email addresses i would have an index of 2 so question is how can i only patch the array with index 1